# cannot launch the Visual Studio C++ Mathematica program on debug mode, only on release mode!

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, c++

Edited
I am trying to run a C++ program on Visual Studio. this program needs to connect to mathematica kernel. assume any simple program, no matters. something like this
code. I added and linked wstp64i4.dll, wstp64i4m.lib, wstp64i4s.lib and wstp64i4.lib.

```
env = WSInitialize((char*)0);
if (env == (WSENV)0)
{
    printf("unable to initialize environment");
}

ml = WSOpenString(env, "-linkname \"C:/Program Files/Wolfram Research/Mathematica/10.4/MathKernel.exe -mathlink\"", &error);
```

This program starts fine on **RELEASE MODE** on Visual studio but **NOT on Debug mode**. I really need to start it on debug mode. When I start on debug it shows me lots of error, one of the errors : (Again the code works fine on Release mode so i think there is no problem with these two lines of code)

`Error  LNK2005 "public: virtual __cdecl std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(void)" (??1?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@UEAA@XZ) already defined in wstp64i4s.lib(mlservicediscovery.obj)   FxDomain    E:\ProgrammingProjects\PhD\FxDomain\FxDomain\msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP140D.dll)`

Comment: In order for this to be answerable, you would need to describe what you are doing, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead, in much greater detail. Preferably provide a minimal example. Note that without these improvements, the question is very likely to be closed, for the simple reason that without more information people can only guess about not only what the problem is, but also about what you were doing ...

Comment: thanks I really dont know what information you mean, I will provide definitely. ok I edited the problem but the whole story is very simple c++ program which tries to connect to mathematica kernel, runs on release mode but not on debug mode.

Comment: See here for guidance: http://sscce.org/ If you provide a minimal example, it will save having to ask many avoidable questions. "the whole story is very simple" <- In that case a minimal example will be easy to construct.

Comment: I edited my question, please let me know if it is not clear yet.

Comment: This is still far from a complete example and does not follow the guidelines I gave you. If you keep it like this, your chances of a useful answer are reduced. There is no complete program and no comments on how you compiled the program (compilation and linking flags, etc.)

Comment: However, now we can see that you are using WSTP (which you did not say) that you receive an error when _linking_ (you said you saw errors when _running_ an presumably successfully compiled/linked program). You say you link to `wstp64i4m.dll`, `wstp64i4s.dll`, but there are no such files. These are `.lib`, not DLL. You should link to _one_ copy of the library, probably the import library `wstp64i4m.lib` (I don't know if you also have to add `wstp64i4.dll`, as I don't actually use the VS GUI). The problem is likely trying to link to multiple different copies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not link against wstp64i4s.lib.  wstp64i4.lib is the only version you should use.

Comment: Is `wstp64i4s.lib` the static version? What is the difference between `wstp64i4.lib` and  `wstp64i4m.lib`? The docs use only the latter.

Comment: Yes the "s" version is a static library.  That variant has a number of asterisks associated with it (at times I regret even asking for it).  The "m" is the same as the wstp64i4.  I'm not sure why that was carried over to the wstp version (because compatibility with previous versions was not necessary).

Comment: fantastic. that was right, thanks a lot, by the way I followed the installation document which says copy paste all those files so i thought i have to link to all,

Comment: The documentation uses only the "m" version: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WSTPDeveloperGuide-Windows.html Was there a difference between the "m" and plain versions for the "ml" libraries?

Comment: you must read the document which you sent more carefully,, here i copied pasted what made me mistake from that.  "Copy the files wstp32i4.lib, wstp32i4m.lib, and wstp32i4s.lib to...." by the way i am new in mathematica. thanks @ihojnicki who helped patiently.

Comment: @Szabolcs, pre-v6 there were "b", "c", "m", and "w" versions.  I think they would map to Borland, cygwin/gcc, Microsoft, and Watcom.  "M" was the only survivor.  Both variants are included in 12.3 (as of today at least).  As for the docs, doing what is documented is always fine.  Those installation steps are in serious need of updating though.

Comment: @Azzurro94, no problem.  Toolchain setup is always difficult the first time around.  Lots of places to trip up and you have get used to reading the tea leaves that are linker error messages.